# Как ограничить движение объекта Unity AR

Tags: android, c#, unity3d, vuforia, ar

Возможно ли ограничить предел передвижения объекта в Unity3d + Vuforia ? Например что бы персонаж не выходил за пределы трека, двигался только по заданной области

Comment: Возможно все, если есть желание. Вам нужно, чтобы ваш объект понял, что он вышел за пределы ( т е как то их уккзать) и потом указать что ему (объекту) в этом случае делать

Comment: Во первых,есть более действенный способ, в unity есть способ ограничение полей,с его помощью можно задать на плоскости нужную площадь, за которую данный объект не будет выходить.

Answer (score 0):

Укажите - если вышел за пределы координат, допустим развернуться либо переместиться в начальную точку.